# Is there a Better way of combining flows in ViewModels in this situation?

Tags: android, kotlin, state-management, kotlin-flow

I have fields in my ui state (TimerSetupState) that can be both updated by *timerItemsFlow* and by directly updating the *_state* variable. Currently I'm updating those fields when *timerItemsFlow* using onEach() and calling _state.update() in the onEach() (updateState() function calls _state.update() internally).

```
    private val timerItemsFlow = repository.getAllTimerItemsStream().onEach { timerItems -> updateState(timerItems) }
        .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), emptyList())
    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(TimerSetupState())
    val state = combine(_state, timerItemsFlow) { state, timerItems -> state }
        .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000), TimerSetupState())
```

If I put the logic of updating the state when *timerItemsFlow* emits in the combine block, then the fields of *_state* flow being updated directly by ui events (calling _state.update() function) will be overwritten. I wonder if there is a better way to stay subscribed to the *timerItemsFlow* without combining with *_state* and just ignoring the value or just generally a better way of what I'm doing right now.

## If you need more context:

[main screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxLop.png)

The user on the main screen picks numbers that will show after x amount of minutes in a notification. I don't want for the user to be able to pick numbers that were already picked and haven't fired a notification yet.

[main screen with added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZIvb.png)

I also don't want the user to be able to pick the same number twice within the same "notification" so when the user adds the number to the "TimeBlock" (Box at the bottom of the screen) the state updates and those numbers become "unavailable".

Also when user opens the app he shouldn't see numbers that didn't already fire a notification, that's why a *timerItemsFlow* is used to update it. But also when the notification fires and the user is still on the main screen, he shouldn't have to close and open the app for those numbers to become available again. That's why flow is used and not a one time read function.

the code is public on GitHub if that helps: https://github.com/TimJeric1/FunTimer

If anyone has any other suggestions relating to the code in the repo, feel free to share it, I would be glad to hear feedback.

---